# Trying to decode this hexadecimal timestamp that represents duration of time

Tags: date, binary, timestamp, hex, decode

I have what is supposed to represent a duration of time, and I think it's in hexadecimal, but I'm not able to figure out how to decode it. I have 4 examples where I know the answer in regular date time format:

```
mapping = {0x00000000:None,
          0x02000000000000004004E640000000006004E640000000002005E640000000004005E640: '6/14/23, 6/21/23',
          0x0200000000000000E007E64000000000E007E64000000000C008E64000000000C008E640: '7/10/23, 7/17/23',
          0x01000000000000006010E640000000006017E640: '9/19/2023'}
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. I've spent a considerable amount of time and can't figure this out.

Thanks so much.